# Script to daily backup sheet snapshot to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a list of values that change every day.
I would like that, once per day, these values get saved as a new line in another sheet with a different structure.
See the image below to understand source and destination sheet structure.

So far I managed to create the basic script to read these value, but how to I create a new row and write them in the destination sheet?

Ideally this would work also if I change the order of the values in the source or destination sheet, e.g. there is a sort of vlookup/match in the header for the destination sheet.

```
function recordHistory() {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }catch(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open('xxx');
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");
  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("B4:C8").getValues();
  
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var destinationHeading = destinationSheet.getRange("A1:F1").getValues();
  
  sourceValues.push(new Array("Date",Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy/MM/dd")));
  
  Logger.log("sourceValues: " + sourceValues);
  Logger.log("sourceValues.length: " + sourceValues.length);
  Logger.log("destinationHeading: " + destinationHeading);
  Logger.log("destinationHeading.length: " + destinationHeading.length);
  
  var sortedDestinationValues = new Array();
  
  destinationHeading.forEach( function (heading) {
    Logger.log("destinationHeading heading: " + heading);
    sourceValues.forEach( function (value) {
      Logger.log("sourceValues value " + value[0] + ": " + value[1]);
      if (value[0] == heading) {
        sortedDestinationValues.push(value[1]);
      }
    });
  });

  Logger.log("newDestinationValues: " + sortedDestinationValues);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(sortedDestinationValues);
};
```

[image]

Comment: `destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceSheet.getRange('B4:B8').getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}));`

Comment: Nice work getting started! Looks like you're on the right track to implementing the basic solution with `.appendRow()` and you should definitely consider Cooper's comment above. For your ideal solution, seems to me that you're well equipped to handle it. (I'd consider using an [Object/Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).) If you get stuck, I think you may find more success in asking a _specific_ question.

Comment: Would be great if you could help with the writing/populating part of the script

Comment: Isn't that what Cooper did? If it doesn't help, [edit] your question to explain why. Also use `@` to address other users

Comment: I updated the script to do a match on the headings of the destination range to rearrange the source value to match the destination columns but in the map() function it says that destinationRange is not defined..

Comment: @Cooper I did another iteration but it still doesn't work. Now the issue is that it sees "destinationHeading" as length=1 so it doesn't loop through it, why is that?

Comment: Please add column letter and row numbers to sheet image.  It's hard to tell what you trying to do.  You code makes no sense to me.  In the future don't add another answer unless you think it's a working answer.  Instead, just add it to your question.

Comment: The answer is working

Answer (score 0):

```
function recordHistory() {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }catch(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open('xxx');
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");
  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("B4:C8").getValues();
  
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var destinationHeading = destinationSheet.getRange("A1:F1").getValues();
  
  sourceValues.push(new Array("Date",Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy/MM/dd")));
  
  Logger.log("sourceValues: " + sourceValues);
  Logger.log("sourceValues.length: " + sourceValues.length);
  Logger.log("destinationHeading: " + destinationHeading);
  Logger.log("destinationHeading.length: " + destinationHeading.length);
  
  var sortedDestinationValues = new Array();
  
  destinationHeading[0].forEach( function (heading) {
    Logger.log("destinationHeading heading: " + heading);
    sourceValues.forEach( function (value) {
      Logger.log("sourceValues value " + value[0] + ": " + value[1]);
      if (value[0] == heading) {
        sortedDestinationValues.push(value[1]);
      }
    });
  });

  Logger.log("newDestinationValues: " + sortedDestinationValues);
  destinationSheet.appendRow(sortedDestinationValues);
};
```